# Euclidean Distance for three (or more) vectors

Tags: r

Say I have the following:

```
a <- c(7,1,9,1,3)
b <- c(4,9,1,3,1)
c <- c(9,1,7,2,2)
```

I know I can get the Euclidean distance of any two of the vectors by doing the following:

dist(rbind(a, b))

Is there a way in R I can get the distances of all possible combinations (i.e, A & B, A & C and B & C), in a single statement?

Comment: can you show the package that has `rdist` function?

Comment: @akrun - I'm sorry. I copied the wrong R code. I corrected my question.

Comment: What about `dist(rbind(a,b,c))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you run `dist(rbind(a,b,c))` the results are a table of euclidean distances.

Comment: Of course, I overlooked the fact you can include multiple vectors in the rbind function.